# Modify field from drop down list Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have this code to have a list of my field in a database.
I have to select one of this element and modify it.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("*", "*", "*") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("Sql860043_2")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
?>
<select name="select1">
<?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <option value="Test"> 
    <?php echo $line['firstname'];?> 
  </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

This is the result:
http://www.mobilesystemsas.it/ale/test1/test1.php
For example i want to select "Alessandro" and modify it to "Giuseppe".
How i can do it?

Comment: Using update Statement?!

Comment: Can you help me with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `select` tag in a `form` tag, and set its *action* attribute to the current php script.

Before performing the query to select all users, check the `$_POST` superglobal for the name of your `select` tag. If it is set, perform a MySQL [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement with that value on the given user.

Here is an example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp):

`UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value`

Note: You  may want to also include a `hidden` tag within the `form` to store the User's ID, which will be necessary in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: The form i create is:
<form action="updatedate" name="select1">
<?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <option value="Test"> 
    <?php echo $line['firstname'];?> 
  </option>
<?php } ?>
</form>
it is correct? i have no idea how to associate an id to every field. Can you help me?